# .Net 4 SP 1 not out yet?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, servicepacks

Where can I download service pack #1 for .Net 4.0 ?

My manager is saying it's 'not secure' to use until SP1 is released. What does it mean ? 
Please advise.

Comment: -1 for your manager.

Comment: I think your manager requires the service pack.

Comment: Where could I download service pack #1 of my manager? :) 
Long time no upgrade...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Currently there is no SP1 version of the 4.0 framework.

I believe your manager is referring to the misguided belief that a Windows product is not reliable / secure / etc ... until there's been at least 1 service pack on it.

Answer (score 1):

Crucial security fixes are being pushed out via Windows Update whenever they are needed, no need for a service pack to keep your install secure (as secure as possible at this time).